# JavaFX Jar doesnt run properly

Tags: java

I edited this question, because I have used a different approach.

When running my JavaFX Application on my RasperryPi (with JDK8) with the following command: sudo java -Djavafx.platform=eglfb -cp ch.seerow.fotomat.app-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jfx.jar com.javafx.main.Main

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.

    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:535)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:224)
    at com.javafx.main.Main$1.run(Main.java:893)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:741)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:711)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:220)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:135)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:123)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:119)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:111)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

I don't think that I'm using any AWT or Swing stuff, so I have no idea where this is comming from.

I'm using Maven to build my project, I use the following dependecies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ch.seerow.fotomat</groupId>
    <artifactId>ch.seerow.fotomat.parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <buildtools.version>0.3</buildtools.version>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <name>Seerow</name>
    </organization>

    <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
          <!-- Test Dependencies -->
          <dependency>
              <groupId>junit</groupId>
              <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
              <version>4.8.2</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
              <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
              <version>1.4</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
              <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
              <version>1.9.5</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
          </dependency>

          <!-- imageJ headless -->
          <dependency>
              <groupId>ch.seerow.common</groupId>
              <artifactId>ch.seerow.common.ijheadless</artifactId>
              <version>1.0</version>
              <type>jar</type>
          </dependency>

          <!-- Image Processing Library -->
          <dependency>
              <groupId>gov.nih.imagej</groupId>
              <artifactId>imagej</artifactId>
              <version>1.46</version>
          </dependency>

          <!-- Amazon Upload Library -->
          <dependency>
              <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
              <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
              <version>1.0.002</version>
          </dependency>

          <!-- log4j Libraries -->
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
              <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
              <version>2.0-beta8</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
              <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
              <version>2.0-beta8</version>
          </dependency>

          <!-- seerow libraries -->
          <dependency>
              <groupId>ch.seerow.common</groupId>
              <artifactId>ch.seerow.common.buildtools</artifactId>
              <version>${buildtools.version}</version>
              <type>jar</type>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-depenency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
                        <logViolationsToConsole>true</logViolationsToConsole>
                        <configLocation>seerow_checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>ch.seerow.common</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ch.seerow.common.buildtools</artifactId>
                            <version>${buildtools.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>check</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

For the ImageJ dependency I used the following solution to get rid of the AWT and Swing stuff (http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/Headless-ImageJ-td3699125.html). But I'm not sure if any other of my dependencies use AWT or SWING.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

before running your app java fx :

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

or in ssh :

```
setenv DISPLAY :0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what would be causing this since I don't work with JavaFX, but I found [a simple tutorial](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/OpenJFX+on+the+Raspberry+Pi) on how to get it running on the Pi.

Besides, why do you use JDK8 instead of using 7? Many devices don't support the latest version yet.

Comment: I use JDk1.8 because this is the only one that supports JavaFX on the raspberry Pi.